# How do I use a session that has different data depending on the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datatable, popup

I have a popup that stores a DataTable into a session so that after the popup is completed and exited, the original page will use that session to rebind its table.
I also have another page that uses the same popup so the session will definitely be the same as the previous one.
If the user has two tabs open, each with one of the pages, they can work with two popups in different tabs and this causes problems to the session because the data in it will flip between the two pages.

Is there a way to only have the session data kept in that tab/window?

Comment: You should be using unique session identifiers. You should never have conflicts of this nature. You will also need aggressive session variable management. This amount of data going in and out of session can become unmanageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to avoid storing large data in sessions. Database call could be an alternative but if you have to use session for each tab use unique names like this. You can distinguish the datatable for each link in the popup code on server side by passing some querystring while opening popup.

```
Session["DataTableForTab_1"]
```

and

```
Session["DataTableForTab_2"]
```

Comment: I would like to use unique names, but both pages use the same popup which only has one name to be generic.

Comment: You can distinguish the datatable for each link in the popup code on server side by passing some querystring while opening popup